# Plotting percentage in seaborn bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

For a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'group': list("AADABCBCCCD"),
     'Values': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})
```

I am trying to plot a barplot showing percentage of times `A, B, C, D` takes zero (or one).

This works:

```
tempdf = df.groupby(['group', 'Values']).Values.count().unstack().fillna(0)
tempdf['total'] = df['group'].value_counts()
tempdf['percent'] = tempdf[0] / tempdf['total'] * 100

tempdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(tempdf)

sns.barplot(x='group', y='percent', data=tempdf)
```

If it were plotting just the mean value, I could simply do `sns.barplot` on `df` dataframe than tempdf. I am not sure how to do it elegantly if I am interested in plotting percentages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use your own function in `sns.barplot` `estimator`, as from [docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

> **estimator** : callable that maps vector -> scalar, optional
>   Statistical function to estimate within each categorical bin.

For you case you could define function as lambda:

```
sns.barplot(x='group', y='Values', data=df, estimator=lambda x: sum(x==0)*100.0/len(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @anton. This works almost perfectly. There was a small problem with division giving no floating point values but including `1.0` works             `sns.barplot(x='group', y='Values', data=df, estimator=lambda x: sum(x==0)*1.0/len(x))`

Comment: @PagMax I'm using python `3.x` so I don't have that, if you're using python 2, you should add `1.0` like you did or if you need `percentage` you could multiply by `100.0`.

Comment: Thanks I understand the difference. Yes I am using python `2.x` and yes multiplying by `100.0` also works but that has to be before the divide operation like `sum(x==0)*100.0/len(x)` instead of `sum(x==0)/len(x)*100.0`. Anyway, problem resolved and thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 21):

You can use Pandas in conjunction with seaborn to make this easier:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
x, y, hue = "day", "proportion", "sex"
hue_order = ["Male", "Female"]

(df[x]
 .groupby(df[hue])
 .value_counts(normalize=True)
 .rename(y)
 .reset_index()
 .pipe((sns.barplot, "data"), x=x, y=y, hue=hue))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can follow these steps so that you can see the count and percentages on top of the bars in your plot. Check the example outputs down below

**with_hue** function will plot percentages on the bar graphs if you have the 'hue' parameter in your plots. It takes the actual graph, feature, Number_of_categories in feature, and hue_categories(number of categories in hue feature) as a parameter.

**without_hue** function will plot percentages on the bar graphs if you have a normal plot. It takes the actual graph and feature as a parameter.

```
def with_hue(plot, feature, Number_of_categories, hue_categories):
    a = [p.get_height() for p in plot.patches]
    patch = [p for p in plot.patches]
    for i in range(Number_of_categories):
        total = feature.value_counts().values[i]
        for j in range(hue_categories):
            percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * a[(j*Number_of_categories + i)]/total)
            x = patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_x() + patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_width() / 2 - 0.15
            y = patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_y() + patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_height() 
            ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
    plt.show()

def without_hue(plot, feature):
    total = len(feature)
    for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2 - 0.05
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This piece of code's really usefull! But I've encountered and corrected a little issue: I was using the `with_hue` function in a subplot with `fig` and `axs` objects, and `ax` wasn't defined! In the `ax.annotate` line I've replaced `ax.annotate` for `plot.annotate`  and this seemed to work!

Comment: feature.value_counts() sorts itself, making feature.value_counts().values[i] iterate unpredictably depending on the contents of the dfs and thus causing the totals to be out of order. so I used feature.value_counts()[feature.unique()] as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855474/changing-sort-in-value-counts

Comment: the iteration is also messed up, although you got the val right in (x,y)-- copypaste error? 
iterate by feature, then subiterate by hue, and for the "bar number" (index of list a that is referred to in the percentage calc) use the same val as in the coordinates (j*Number_of_categories + i).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [library Dexplot](https://dexplo.org/dexplot), which has the ability to return relative frequencies for categorical variables. It has a similar API to Seaborn. Pass the column you would like to get the relative frequency for to the `count` function. If you would like to subdivide this by another column, do so with the `split` parameter. The following returns raw counts.

```
import dexplot as dxp
dxp.count('group', data=df, split='Values')
```

[image]

To get the relative frequencies, set the `normalize` parameter to the column you want to normalize over. Use `True` to normalize over the overall total count.

```
dxp.count('group', data=df, split='Values', normalize='group')
```

[image]

Normalizing over the `'Values'` column would produce the following graph, where the total of all the '0' bars are 1.

```
dxp.count('group', data=df, split='Values', normalize='Values')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For future me:

Seaborn >=0.13.0 offers built-in capability for this via *stat* parameter:

```py
sns.countplot(data=df, x="jobs_successful",hue="jobs_successful",stat="percent")
```

NOTE: `hue` is optional if you want different colors for breakdown of the different categories