# changing sort in value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I do

```
mt = mobile.PattLen.value_counts()   # sort True by default
```

I get

```
4    2831
3    2555 
5    1561
[...]
```

If I do

```
mt = mobile.PattLen.value_counts(sort=False)
```

I get

```
8    225
9    120
2   1234 
[...]
```

What I am trying to do is get the output in 2, 3, 4 ascending order (the left numeric column).  Can I change value_counts somehow or do I need to use a different function.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html), because the left column is called `index`. The full command would be `mt = mobile.PattLen.value_counts().sort_index()`. For example:

```
mobile = pd.DataFrame({'PattLen':[1,1,2,6,6,7,7,7,7,8]})
print (mobile)
   PattLen
0        1
1        1
2        2
3        6
4        6
5        7
6        7
7        7
8        7
9        8

print (mobile.PattLen.value_counts())
7    4
6    2
1    2
8    1
2    1
Name: PattLen, dtype: int64


mt = mobile.PattLen.value_counts().sort_index()
print (mt)
1    2
2    1
6    2
7    4
8    1
Name: PattLen, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Or in case one want's to preserve the order of appearance: `x.value_counts()[x.unique()]`

Comment: @normanius Weird that unique() works there. Can you explain why?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Be `x` a pd.Series. According to the documentation, [`idx=x.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) represents the unique values in order of appearance (as a numpy array). `y=value_counts()` is a series indexed by the unique values of `x`. Finally, `y[idx]`, similar as `y.loc[idx]`, selects elements of series `y` by its index. See documentation ["Selection by Label"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-label). HTH

Answer (score 9):

As hinted by normanius’ comment under jezrael’s answer :

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,2,6,6,7,7,7,7,8]})
>>> df.a.value_counts()[df.a.unique()]
1    2
2    1
6    2
7    4
8    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

one can sort by any order by providing a custom index explicitely :

```
>>> df.a.value_counts()[[8,7,6,2,1]]
8    1
7    4
6    2
2    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>> df.a.value_counts()[[1,8,6,2,7]]
1    2
8    1
6    2
2    1
7    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

This is of particular interest for **plotting categorical data** :

```
>>> df.a.value_counts()[['hourly','daily','weekly','monthly']].plot(type="bar")
```

Anecdotically, it can be used to remove some entries or to make others appear several times :

```
>>> df.a.value_counts()[[1,1,1,8]]
1    2
1    2
1    2
8    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

use sort_values if you want largest to smallest horizontal bars

```
 df['education'].value_counts().sort_values().plot.barh()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# load the 'tips' dataset from seaborn
tips_data = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips_data['size'].value_counts().**sort_index(0)**
```

Comment: If you want to highlight the part of **sort_index(0)**, please avoid doing it in the code itself. You can write a description as part of your answer. If you let your answer in this way, people who see it can confuse themselves.

Comment: Please be more elaborate, provide an [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) for your answer.