# Plot the counted values in each column of a data frame in a separate plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm very new to Python and am trying to plot all the columns in my data frame in separate plots.

The data frame has 45 columns which are all called, V1_category V2_category V3_category V4_category V5_category V6_category V7_category etc. till V45_category.

Each entry has one of the four values: neutral, pleasant, unpleasant, painful. I need to somehow count how often these 4 values occur in each of the 45 columns and then plot these as 45 individual histograms (possibly in one figure?). I want the plots to be nicely formatted so I guess matplotlib would be the most useful?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is a barplot. There are many options for visualization these categories, [see more at the vignette for seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

Below I try to make a data.frame that looks like yours:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

categories = ['neutral','pleasant','unpleasant','painful']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(categories,(100,45)),
                  columns=["V"+str(i)+"_category" for i in np.arange(1,46)])
```

To use it in seaborn, your data.frame needs to be long, so we can pivot it like:

```
df.melt() 

    variable    value
0   V1_category neutral
1   V1_category unpleasant
2   V1_category pleasant
3   V1_category unpleasant
4   V1_category unpleasant
```

And we pass this directly into seaborn:

```
sns.catplot('value',data=df.melt(),col="variable",
kind="count",col_wrap=5,height=5, aspect=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks so much, that worked perfectly! Much appreciated! :) 

I have one more question, instead of displaying the values on the y-axis as counts, could I display it as a percentage? So if 10 out of 40 people voted 'neutral', could I display that as 25%?

Comment: Hi @SophieMQ, you're welcome. For that, you would need to calculate the percentage first. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692781/python-plotting-percentage-in-seaborn-bar-plot, except you need to facet it

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I tried all the suggested options and it doesn't seem to work. Not sure how to facet it? Also, should I calculate the percentages first or can I do it as I plot?

Comment: Hi @SophieMQ, i think you are asking a different question and it's quite vague what you mean by "doesn't seem to work". I would suggest you post it as another question with more information about your dataset and what works