# in python, using Seaborn library, is there any way I can add percentage ticks to my graphs values?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, data-analysis

I have a dataset with binary values, and continuous values, I created a loop to plot them using Seaborn and I want a percentage stating the proportion of each column. any ideas?

```
#lets set the visual palet and figure and grid size
sns.set_palette('Accent')
plt.figure(figsize=(15,18))
the_grid = GridSpec(5, 3)
#loop thrue the dataframs features and plot them, use countplot if they are binary and distplot if they are not binary
for i,column in enumerate(gym_churn.drop('churn', axis=1).columns):
    plt.subplot(the_grid[i//3, i%3], title=column.replace('_',' '))
    if gym_churn[column].unique().sum() == 1:
        sns.countplot(x=column, hue='churn', data=gym_churn)
        plt.xlabel('')
        plt.ylabel('')
        plt.gca().get_legend().remove()
        
        if column == 'near_location':
            legend = gym_churn['churn'].unique()
            plt.legend(legend, shadow=True, fancybox=True, title='churn', loc='best')
    if gym_churn[column].unique().sum() > 1:
        sns.distplot(gym_churn[gym_churn['churn'] == 0][column], hist = False, kde = True, kde_kws = {'bw' : 1})
        sns.distplot(gym_churn[gym_churn['churn'] == 1][column], hist = False, kde = True, kde_kws = {'bw' : 1})
        plt.xlabel('')
        plt.ylabel('')
    


plt.suptitle('Feature Distribution', fontsize = 14)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: here is how the graphs look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you need is `annotate`. You can write whatever on the plot using this command.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692781/python-plotting-percentage-in-seaborn-bar-plot) (**Deepak Natarajan** answer) there is stack overflow answered where you can find the code. In your case, you need the function with_hue. I attach it:

```
def with_hue(plot, feature, Number_of_categories, hue_categories):
    a = [p.get_height() for p in plot.patches]
    patch = [p for p in plot.patches]
    for i in range(Number_of_categories):
        total = feature.value_counts().values[i]
        for j in range(hue_categories):
            percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * a[(j*Number_of_categories + i)]/total)
            x = patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_x() + patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_width() / 2 - 0.15
            y = patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_y() + patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_height() 
            ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
    plt.show()

def without_hue(plot, feature):
    total = len(feature)
    for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2 - 0.05
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
    plt.show()
```

On the link, check how to use the function, you will need to first create a `countplot`.